# Laravel required_if and mimes not working on file input

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

**Code in request file**

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'type' =>'required|in:1,2',
        'add' => 'required_if:type,2|in:1,2',
        'image' => 'required_if:add,2|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,webp|max:10000'
    ];
}
```

The add attribute select box has 2 option:

1. Don't upload image
2. Upload image

On **image** attribute I did use required_if **add** attribute has value 2 (i.e. option 2, I want to add image) only then make image field to be a required field and mimes and max file size validation.

But the problem is when option one is selected from add select box which mean I don't want to upload image and then user submit form this throws validation: 
**The image must be a file of type: jpeg, jpg, png, webp.**
As per my validation code it should ignore it as it is required only if option 2 is selected then why this mimes validation error throws up.

Comment: what error you're getting? can you please add some controller code?

Comment: The above code is in request file where I am validating inputs.

Comment: What I am doing is validate img file only if user selects upload image "Yes" from select box. But when upload img "no" option is selected the image validation throws The image must be a file of type: jpeg, jpg, png, webp validation error which belongs to mimes rule instead of ignoring it as the option value is "no"

Comment: try to add `sometimes` before `required_if` in image validation and then try.

Comment: I did try with sometimes and nullable same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can simply add nullable after required_if

```
'cover'=>['required_if:can_upload_file,true','nullable','mimes:jpeg,jpg,png','max:5120']
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code

```
 return [
    'image.*' => 'nullable',
    'image.required' => 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,webp|max:10000'
  ]
```